Media elements such as <audio> and <video> must have a <track> for captions eslint error
When I try to add
<video controls>
  <source src="content.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="content.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support the video.
</video>

in my react js project, Eslint throws the following error :-

Media elements such as < audio > and < video > must have a < track > for
captions.

Any idea what is this? And how should I fix this in the best way??

This is my solution. Just give it a try
Based on my understanding of your question, it seems you're seeking information about adding a subtitles track. You can find details on how to do this here:
MDN Link
To include a subtitles track, you need to modify your  tag like this:
<video controls>
  <track default kind="captions" srclang="en" src="SUBTITLE_PATH" />
  <source src="content.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="content.webm" type="video/webm" />
  Your browser does not support the video.
</video>

If you prefer not to include a subtitles file, you can leave the src attribute empty to avoid the eslint warning.

The error you're encountering with ESLint is related to the requirement for media elements such as <audio> and <video> to have a <track> element for captions. To resolve this issue, you can add an empty <track> element within the <video> tag. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to include the empty <track> element:
<video controls>
  <source src="content.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="content.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <track kind="captions" src="captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default />
  Your browser does not support the video.
</video>


The <track> element is added with the kind attribute set to "captions" to indicate that it is a captions track.
The src attribute specifies the URL of the captions file, and srclang specifies the language of the captions.
The label attribute provides a label for the captions track.
The default attribute indicates that this track should be the default captions track.

By including the empty <track> element, you address the requirement for media elements to have a captions track, resolving the ESLint error.
